# Amchart4 date axis grouping creating incorrect groups

Tags: javascript, histogram, amcharts, amcharts4

Im trying to create histogram using amchart library (v4). My goal is simple histogram over set of dates with numerical values. The key of the histogram should be grouping of close dates into single chart bar. I create [codepen example](https://codepen.io/Daniel-Dvon/pen/RwEjdOP) with 12 date values .

The problem is that most of the time grouping is not working correctly at the moment when the dates should be grouped. Some specific dates are grouped into wrong group when changing the chart scope view.

For example, within test data there is date (6th January 2021 17:02):

```
{
   date: new Date(2021, 1, 6, 17, 2, 33, 543),
   value: 5
}
```

and it is correctly displayed when chart is zoomed in using horizontal scrollbar:
[image: Histogram detail view of 6th January]
Also 10th January displaying only value **1** but should displaying value 2 since in data there are 2 dates for 10th january and both with value **1**

When chart is zoomed out so i can see whole chart, multiple dates are grouped into group for 10th january (also mentioned 6th January with value **5**) column which is not correcr. Also whole chart is acting weird when using scrollbars.
[image: Whole carch view with incorrect grouping]

I already spend many hours to figure it out but I'm not able to fix this problem. Am I missing some chart settings? Do I have incorrect data?

Answer (score 0):

After additional hour of investigation i found out where is the problem.

Obviosly **amcharts4 needs data in timestamp DESCENDING sort order** (from oldest dates to newest) to group dates correctly.

Tried to find out some mention about this data order requirment in amcharts documentations but I didn't find anything there.

After all, try to avoind unsorted dates data sets or ones with ascending sort order when working with amcharts.